# Slurm: Why use srun inside sbatch?

Tags: hpc, slurm

In a sbatch script, you can directly launch programs or scripts (for example an executable file `myapp`) but in many tutorials people use `srun myapp` instead.

Despite reading some documentation on the topic, **I do not understand the difference and when to use each of those syntaxes**.

I hope this question is precise enough (1st question on SO), thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: is the scenario you have the same as the submission script I provided as an example in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72092272/do-sbatch-submission-scripts-in-slurm-really-need-the-srun-command-to-run-intend ?

Comment: can you provide an example sbatch submission script for your question?

Comment: @CharlieParker This question dates from my previous job: I don't have any access to a Slurm HPC now and won't be able to provide any reliable example ‍♂️

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `srun` command is used to create job 'steps'.

First, it will bring **better reporting** of the resource usage ; the [sstat](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sstat.html) command will provide real-time resource usage for processes that are started with `srun`, and each step (each call to srun) will be reported individually in the accounting.

Second, it can be used to **setup many instances of a serial program** (program that only use one CPU) into a single job, and micro-schedule those programs inside the job allocation.

Finally, for parallel jobs, `srun` will also play the important role **of starting the parallel program** and setup the parallel environment. It will start as many instances of the program as were requested with the `--ntasks` option on the CPUs that were allocated for the job. In the case of a [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) program, it will also handle the communication between the MPI library and Slurm.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this precise answer

Comment: In the case of setting up many instances of a serial program, a typical case is `srun -N1 -n1 myprog &` right? If the sbatch job allocation is over > 1 node, then will `srun` ensure each instance runs on an independent CPU better than just `myprog &`? In fact, what happens if the script simply has `myprog &` and the allocation is over > 1 node?

Comment: if the script simply has `myprog &` and the allocation is over > 1 node, only the first node will have processes running, and those processes will fight for access to the same CPUs

Comment: what if I have GPUs -- single and multiple?

Comment: would an example run with srun be `srun python main.py`? Asking cuz I only know with `srun hostname`